# Ember : Render Template using cached model

Tags: ember.js

I have a data object which i have stored from the response of the first request. If I go back to the old page, how do I render the template using the cached object without sending another request.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using ember-data v2...

Have a look at the `shouldBackgroundReloadAll` and `shouldBackgroundReloadRecord` methods on `DS.Adapter`.

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html#method_shouldBackgroundReloadAll

If you override these methods in your adapter class to return `false`, then ember-data will not re-fetch records from the server if it already has the record cached.

More information here: http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html#toc_new-adapter-hooks-for-better-caching

Answer (score 0):

If you have records that you wish to store statically across requests, you should create a service and store it there. Services are singletons, which retain state between route transitions.